# onbackpressed method error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using authentication to enter into a page, after authenticated only the user enters into the page. i wrote a code for onbackpressed(), but it is not working. Here DatabaseDemo and Login are the two classes. when i press the back button the login class with username and password is displaying.

DatabaseDemo.java

```
public class DatabaseDemo extends TabActivity {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    GridView grid;
    TextView txtTest;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SetupTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Add Employee");
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        //Add employee
        case 1:
            Intent addIntent=new Intent(this,AddEmployee.class);
            startActivity(addIntent);
            break;
        }
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return false;
    }
    void SetupTabs()
    {
        TabHost host=getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec=host.newTabSpec("tag1");
        Intent in1=new Intent(this, AddEmployee.class);
        spec.setIndicator("Add Employee");
        spec.setContent(in1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2=host.newTabSpec("tag2");
        Intent in2=new Intent(this, GridList.class);

        spec2.setIndicator("Employees");
        spec2.setContent(in2);

        host.addTab(spec);
        host.addTab(spec2);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseDemo.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I am having some more classes, it is working fine for the other intents.

Login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn;
    EditText et1, et2;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Leditename);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Leditpw);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String ename = et1.getText().toString().trim();
        System.out.println("ename is..." +ename);
        String epw = et2.getText().toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Password is..." +epw);

        if(ename.equals("srikanth") && epw.equals("12345")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "valid login..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseDemo.class);
            startActivity(in);      
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid authentication..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Logcat is showing no error.

```
02-14 17:45:33.595: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.databaseex/.DatabaseDemo }
02-14 17:45:34.835: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.databaseex/.DatabaseDemo: 1141 ms (total 1141 ms)
02-14 17:45:50.145: I/System.out(613): ename is...srikanth
02-14 17:45:50.145: I/System.out(613): Password is...12345
02-14 17:45:50.175: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.databaseex/.DatabaseDemo }
02-14 17:45:51.055: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.databaseex/.DatabaseDemo: 819 ms (total 819 ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to skip `super.onBackPressed();` line:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseDemo.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: i pasted my logcat here.. and am not getting any error in the logcat.. even if i delete the onBackPressed() method  it working like this only..

Comment: even if ignoring onBackPressed still causes the same problem then i believe there must be something else wrong in your code

Comment: can u give me your email id, so that i can send my code to your mail.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d5vvcM70 is the link for my code, i put 6 classes there, and i skipped the 3 classes that do the normal things like set value, get value,and DialogListener, utilities classes. please see this and ask me if you want some more..

Comment: what is `TabHost host=getTabHost();` in your *DatabaseDemo.java*? I guess it should be something like `TabHost host=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.your_tabhost_id_in_layout);`. Fix this and i hope it should work

Comment: it's working fine when i use a new button instead of onBackpressed. i tried doing TabHost host=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.your_tabhost_id_in_layout); also, but it's getting error..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of onBackpressed method use onkeydown()

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseDemo.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: i tried doing this also but there is no result. once go through this link, u'll find some more code of my programme. pastebin.com/d5vvcM70

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseDemo.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

this is working perfectly , please check your androidmanifest file first , is there entry for activity Login ?  if there , then no any issue otherwise make activity login in manifest file

Comment: Login is the first activity that comes at startup, is it need to add another time in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

override method onBackPressed in activity as bellow

```
@Override     
public void onBackPressed(){         
  Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseDemo.this, Login.class);  
  startActivity(i);    
}
```